# Is there a way to specify Angular configurations within karma.conf.js in IntelliJ?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, karma-runner, webstorm, angular7

We have two different configurations (before Angular 6 called environments) for our Angular app. Now we run Karma test and I don't find an option within IntelliJ/WebStorm, how to specify the correct configuration.

I've found something "old", which was defined in the karma.config.js, like this:

```
config.set({
...
  plugins: [
    ...
    require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
  ]
  angularCli: {
    environment: 'dev'
  }
});
```

But this seem not to work anymore, also with the newer Angular version, the plugin changed to `require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma")`.

Is there a way to start a Karma test within IntelliJ/WebStorm with a specific configuration?

From terminal it is easy - `ng test --configuration=dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be possible in upcoming IDEA 2019.1 - it allows passing cli arguments in **karma** run configuration (see [WEB-29620](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29620)) using **karma options:** field (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/run-debug-configuration-karma.html):

[image]